# Single word for non-domestic errands

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that describes non-domestic errands like filing taxes, paying credit card bills, printing job related documents, filing an application for a driving license, etc.?

For example, if I were to dedicate my entire week to do only the above type of tasks, I would like to say this:

"My entire next week is dedicated to ________."

I need a single word that fills the blank above.

Comment: Colloquially, you could use _adulting_ here.

Comment: It is unclear what is meant by *non-domestic* here. Job-related activities are clearly not domestic, but everything related to the management of one's household could be characterised as domestic.

Comment: I think going on vacation would be *non-domestic*. In any case, I can think of no single word that means "all activities that are non-domestic." Certainly none of the answers currently provided apply—you can easily have *domestic chores*, *domestic errands* and *domestic paperwork*. Unless, of course, you are defining *domestic* in a particular way that you haven't stated.

Answer (score 1):

All of the exemplified tasks are forms of [paperwork](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/paperwork), which is defined by Collins English Dictionary—Complete & Unabridged 12th edition (©2014) defines it as meaning:

> clerical work, such as the completion of forms or the writing of reports or letters

Similarly the American Heritage Dictionary 5th edition (©2016) defines it as meaning:

> Work involving the handling of reports, letters, and forms.

Most of what you describe involves filling out forms. I am sure I do not need to prove that to you since you already know you will be be filling out tax forums alone for days to come. Paying the bills which still counts since the bill traditionally came in the mail as a paper letter, and printing documents is part of the handling. It specifically relates to clerical work and paper, so any common household chores are excluded by definition, and perhaps any task which does not at least have a historical relationship with paper.

Raking, mowing the lawn, watering the plants, doing the dishes, mopping the floor, vacuuming and dusting are all categorically ruled out as candidates, so nobody will mistakenly think that your week is dedicated to that sort of task.

Dedicated to paperwork is a perfectly valid collocate too, for example, in the United States [Congressional Record](https://books.google.com/books?id=2dHCW34Ctn8C&q=%22dedicated+to+paperwork%22&dq=%22dedicated+to+paperwork%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT7ti1xs_fAhV0FTQIHWUzAmkQ6AEIUDAH) of 1999 you can see the following sentence:

> How many of those staff could be better utilized in classrooms across the district instead of spending their time dedicated to paperwork?

You might also see some cop movies where officers who prefer to be on-the-beat decry being knees deep in paperwork, although specific examples do not come to mind right now.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness (although I agree the two previous answers have good merit) I am proposing

> "My entire next week is dedicated to **administration**."

However I would normally *out of context* use lbf's suggested quality description

"My entire next week is dedicated to **administrative chores**." or

> "My entire next week is dedicated to **household administration**."

Answer (score 0):

> "My entire next week is dedicated to **chores**."

**chore** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/chore)

> 1. A routine or minor duty or task.

And:

chore noun [ C ]. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/chore)

​

> a job or piece of work that needs to be done regularly:
>
> ​A chore is also something that is difficult and unpleasant:

Chores are not just for kids around the home.  As in:

By the time he’d finished all the chores and gotten home, it was mid-afternoon.

An **errand** may work:

> A short trip taken to perform a specified task, usually for another

but In AmE, this can imply a task at others behest.

Comment: Can "errands" also be the word I am looking for? "My entire next week is dedicated to **errands**."" Does "chores" better capture the *non-domestic* part of the meaning or is "errands" also an equally good word for this purpose?

Comment: errand:  a short trip taken to perform a specified task, usually for another!  Many in AmE call paying bills, visiting doctor etc ... personal errands or chores!

Answer (score 0):

There is in current BrE a very simple two syllable word that conveys simultaneously tedium and necessity: it is "admin". I know it is an abbreviation of a longer word but my point is that the longer word fails to convey the emotion.

Answer (score 0):

"I am getting some paperwork done" or "I am doing some paperwork" could be a casual way to describe the tasks you have mentioned as examples. Certainly, buying groceries or watering plants dont count as paperwork so no one would think you are doing these domestic chores.